# How to configure god/redis for two environments?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, god

I want to use [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/) to monitor my [redis server](http://redis.io/). The problem is that they are in different locations locally and on my server. I tried doing something like this but this causes god to fail.

```
%w{6379}.each do |port|
  God.watch do |w| 
    w.name = "redis" 
    w.interval = 30.seconds 
    if RAILS_ENV == 'development'
      w.start = "/usr/local/bin/redis-server /usr/local/bin" 
      w.stop = "/usr/local/bin/redis-cli -p 6379 shutdown" 
    else # in production
      w.start = "/usr/local/etc/redis-server /usr/local/etc" 
      w.stop = "/usr/local/etc/redis-cli -p 6379 shutdown"
    end 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == 'development'
```

And then call your script using

```
RAILS_ENV=development sudo god ...
```

in your dev environment.

and in production:

```
sudo god ...
```

Comment: Do you need sudo? I've been running it without root access without any issues so far.